# How can I call a postres procedure with one or more INOUT parameters from java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, callable-statement

There is a stored procedure in postgresql 11:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE clone_ad (
    p_src_ad_id BIGINT,
    p_ad_def_id BIGINT,
    p_user_id BIGINT,
    p_dst_ad_id INOUT BIGINT)
AS ...
```

It works perfect but I can't call it from my java code :-(

I have postgresql 11 and java 8. I tried two postgres jdbc drivers org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5 and postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4 result is the same

when I use

```
       stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call clone_ad(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
       stmt.setLong(1,1L);
       stmt.setLong(2,1000L);
       stmt.setLong(3,999L);
       stmt.setObject(4,null, Types.BIGINT);
       stmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.BIGINT);
       boolean hadResults = stmt.execute();
```

java throws:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: clone_ad(bigint, bigint, bigint, bigint) is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.

and when I use

```
       stmt = conn.prepareCall("call clone_ad(?, ?, ?, ?)");
       stmt.setLong(1,1L);
       stmt.setLong(2,1000L);
       stmt.setLong(3,999L);
       stmt.setObject(4,null, Types.BIGINT);
       stmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.BIGINT);
       boolean hadResults = stmt.execute();
```

java throws:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement does not declare an OUT parameter.  Use { ?= call ... } to declare one.

Calling of another procedure without INOUT parameters works a I expect.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc driver contains bug but cannot be fixed easy because it breaks backward compatibility :-(

see details: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/1475

Answer (score 0):

You can read [CallableStatements and INOUT Parameters](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefjdbc75719.html)